# Jquery doesnt work on modal Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

Hello I'm trying to enable/disabled an input depending on select value, all this in a modal, but it doesn't seem to work.

The idea is that if my estado_rx is Cerrado and I select Abierto, the input of Fecha Apertura, and the select for Responsable should enable, otherwise they should be disabled.

Is quite similar when my estado_rx is Abierto or Alicuota and I select Agotado, the input of Fecha Agotado should enable, otherwise it should be disabled.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-slide-in-right" aria-hiden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-status-{{$rx->id_rx}}">

    {!!Form::model($rx,['method'=>'PUT','route'=>['reactivos.update',$rx->id_rx]])!!}
    {{Form::token()}}

<?php

$usuarios=DB::table('users')->get();

?>

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Cambiar estado de reactivo</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>¿Desea cambiar el estado del reactivo: <b>{{ $rx->nom_rx }}</b>?</p>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="estado_rx" class="col-md-12" control-label"><b>Estado</b></label>
                    <select name="estado_rx" class="form-control" required id="staterx">
                        @if ($rx->estado_rx=='Cerrado')
                        <option value="Abierto">Abierto</option>
                        <option value="Cerrado" selected>Cerrado</option>
                        @elseif ($rx->estado_rx=='Abierto')
                        <option value="Abierto" selected>Abierto</option>
                        <option value="Agotado">Agotado</option>
                        @elseif ($rx->estado_rx=='Alícuota')
                        <option value="Alícuota" selected>Alícuota</option>
                        <option value="Agotado">Agotado</option>
                        @endif
                    </select>
                </div>

                @if ($rx->estado_rx=='Cerrado')
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="fecha_aper"><b>Fecha Apertura</b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker-only-init" name="fecha_aper" id="f_aper" disabled/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="responsable_rx"><b>Responsable</b></label>
                    <select name="responsable_rx" class="form-control" id="responsable" disabled>
                        <option value="" selected> </option>
                        @foreach ($usuarios as $user)
                            <option value="{{$user->name}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                @endif

                @if (($rx->estado_rx=='Abierto')||($rx->estado_rx=='Alícuota'))
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="fecha_agotado"><b>Fecha en que se agotó</b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker-only-init" name="fecha_agotado" id="f_ago"/>
                </div>
                @endif

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Aceptar</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{Form::Close()}}


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#staterx').change(function() {
    if( $(this).val() == 'Agotado') {
        $('#f_ago').prop( "disabled", false );
    } else {       
        $('#f_ago').prop( "disabled", true );
    }
});
</script>
```

How can I use Jquery function to do this inside a modal? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to work?" Does your drop down change event fire when you set the drop down? Do you get any errors in your browser console window?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: The input is always enable, doesnt disable when i select the other values